# Docker Golang SDK - How to redirect container stdout to a file

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Using the docker golang sdk the following method can be used to create a container and bind it's output to `stdout`.

```
resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image:        "alpine",
        Cmd:          []string{"echo", "Hello World"},
        AttachStdout: true,
    }, nil, nil, "")
```

How can I redirect this output to a file using the SDK ?
I'm using the official SDK of docker - `github.com/docker/docker/client`

Comment: When you ask something about how to use a package on Golang, it helps if you provide the full import path (github or whatever) of that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
  out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerLogsOptions{ShowStdout: true})
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  f, err := os.Create("/tmp/clogs")

  io.Copy(f, out)
```

But make sure to to do that after you have started the container, Create will only create the container and not start it

Comment: This is actually wrong, because the docker log format has a header for each message, and you output garbled text if done this way: https://ahmet.im/blog/docker-logs-api-binary-format-explained/

Comment: At the time of commenting this, Docker SDK now has `stdcopy.StdCopy` which can deal with multiple streams. @FrancescoPasa

Answer (score 0):

The format of docker logs contains 8 bytes of header for each message, indicating for instance whether the output was on `stdout` or `stderr`. So one cannot simply copy the log output to a destination as Tarun Lalwani is mentioning in the other answer, because the header would then be interpreted as characters, garbling the output.

Unfortunately the client docs don't even mention the issue. [This article](https://ahmet.im/blog/docker-logs-api-binary-format-explained/) explains it a bit and offers a library to solve the issue:

```golang
import (
  "github.com/docker/docker/client"
  "github.com/ahmetb/dlog"
)
  
// ---

reader, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, resp.ID, nil)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

file, err := os.Create("/path/to/your/file")
io.Copy(file, dlog.NewReader(reader))
```